# How can I get ''OHLC'' data rather the Close only?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD","all","1/23/2005","50")
```

The code above just fetch the `close` rate and leaves the other columns blank. How to fix that?

Comment: could you explain a bit more about your issue ?

Comment: I was trying to fetch the Open, High, Low, Close, Volume information for the Currency pair "EUROUSD", for the following 50 days of the one mentioned in the formula... But I get the Closing rate only.

Comment: oldest you can get is 2/4/2014 16:00:00 for EUR and 2/1/2007 16:00:00 for USD

Comment: @Rana Please note that comments are meant to be temporary. Salient information related to your question should be [edit]ed into your question post.

Answer (score 2):

to get the whole set of **Open | High | Low | Close | Volume** you need to use one currency per the formula:

- **`=GOOGLEFINANCE("USD", "ALL", TODAY()-1)`**
- **`=GOOGLEFINANCE("EUR", "ALL", TODAY()-1)`**
  [image]

another drawback is historical data limitation:

- for **`USD`** it's **`2/1/2007 16:00:00`**
- for **`EUR`** it's **`2/4/2014 16:00:00`**

that can be checked with these formulas:

- **`=GOOGLEFINANCE("USD", "ALL", DATE(2005, 1, 23), TODAY()-2000, "DAILY")`**
- **`=GOOGLEFINANCE("EUR", "ALL", DATE(2005, 1, 23), TODAY()-1600, "DAILY")`**

here is a spreadsheet for a view: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PllLdPfYeM4ojL13vlW9H8Qr16hLmpfxJboOCl63d3I/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

Comment: That's great... but I wonder there must be a pair otherwise how do I value a currency...  or how do I know which currency OHLC values are referring to?

Comment: @Rana exactly... if you will have a pair of currencies how you should know to which are OHLV data referring to... but I guess the main problem is that there are no data for 1/23/2005 nor any closer to that date you are trying to lookup

Comment: Your code works but I don't understand the base currency the USD or EUR (OHLCV) values are being displayed. Could you explain?